# GraphQL Federation Nodemon breaks Gateway on Restart

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nodemon, apollo-federation

I'm struggeling to setup my GraphQL Federation development environment. I have a few services and I want the server to automatically restart whenever a file changes. I am using Typescript, so Typescript has to transpile first into the dist folder and then nodemon should restart the service where the change happended.

I created the following setup in my package.json file:

```
"dev": "concurrently -k \"tsc -w\" \"npm:dev:*\"",
"dev:accounts": "nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/accounts ./dist/services/accounts/index.js",
"dev:profiles": "nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/profiles ./dist/services/profiles/index.js",
"dev:gateway": "wait-on tcp:4001 tcp:4002 && nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js"
```

---

This works in the beginning when I run `npm run dev` - the accounts and profiles services start and once they are running, the gateway starts.
However, as soon as Typescript is finished transpiling, nodemon restarts all services and the gateway, because the files in the dist folder have been changed.

Here is the issue. Nodemon restarts the services and gateway independently and the gateway restarts faster, which means that the gateway is running before the services, resulting in the following error:

```
[dev:gateway] Error checking for changes to service definitions: Couldn't load service definitions for "profiles" at http://localhost:4002: request to http://localhost:4002/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4002    
[dev:gateway] This data graph is missing a valid configuration. Couldn't load service definitions for "profiles" at http://localhost:4002: request to http://localhost:4002/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4002
```

I couldn't figure out how to tell nodemon to wait until every services has restarted whenever nodemon is performing a restart!

**Because right now the wait-on only works on the first inital execution of `npm run dev`. After that for every change nodemon is responsible for the restarts and does not care about wait-on.**

---

Here is the entire trainwreck:

$ npm run dev

```
> my-app@1.0.0 dev
> concurrently -k "tsc -w" "npm:dev:*"

17:08:48 - Starting compilation in watch mode...

[dev:accounts] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:accounts
[dev:accounts] > nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/accounts ./dist/services/accounts/index.js

[dev:gateway] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:gateway
[dev:gateway] > wait-on tcp:4001 tcp:4002 && nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js

[dev:profiles] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:profiles
[dev:profiles] > nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/profiles ./dist/services/profiles/index.js

[dev:accounts] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] watching path(s): dist/services/accounts/**/*
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/accounts/index.js`

[dev:profiles] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] watching path(s): dist/services/profiles/**/*
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/profiles/index.js`

[dev:accounts] Accounts service ready at http://localhost:4001/
[dev:profiles] Profiles service ready at http://localhost:4002/

[dev:gateway] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js`

[dev:gateway]  Server started at http://localhost:4000/graphql

[dev:accounts] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:accounts
[dev:accounts] > nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/accounts ./dist/services/accounts/index.js

[dev:gateway] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:gateway
[dev:gateway] > wait-on tcp:4001 tcp:4002 && nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js

[dev:profiles] > my-app@1.0.0 dev:profiles
[dev:profiles] > nodemon -r dotenv/config -r esm --watch ./dist/services/profiles ./dist/services/profiles/index.js

[dev:accounts] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] watching path(s): dist/services/accounts/**/*
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/accounts/index.js`

[dev:profiles] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] watching path(s): dist/services/profiles/**/*
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/profiles/index.js`

[dev:accounts] Accounts service ready at http://localhost:4001/

[dev:profiles] Profiles service ready at http://localhost:4002/

[dev:gateway] [nodemon] 2.0.7
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js`

[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...

Typescript doing stuff...
[0] 17:08:57 - Found 226 errors. Watching for file changes.

[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js`
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:accounts] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/accounts/index.js`
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/profiles/index.js`
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:profiles] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/services/profiles/index.js`
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[dev:gateway] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...

[dev:gateway] [nodemon] starting `node -r dotenv/config -r esm ./dist/index.js`

[dev:accounts] Accounts service ready at http://localhost:4001/

[dev:gateway]  Server started at http://localhost:4000/graphql

[dev:gateway] Error checking for changes to service definitions: Couldn't load service definitions for "profiles" at http://localhost:4002: request to http://localhost:4002/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4002

[dev:gateway] This data graph is missing a valid configuration. Couldn't load service definitions for "profiles" at http://localhost:4002: request to http://localhost:4002/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4002

[dev:profiles] Profiles service ready at http://localhost:4002/
```

---

I hope this is understandable and I'm looking forward to any suggestions on how I could fix this.

Thanks, Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using wait-on in your code rather than in your package.json scripts. Make sure to wrap your gateway server with the wait-on code.
Example:

```js
import waitOn from 'wait-on'
import app from './config/app'
import server from './config/apollo'

const port = process.env.PORT

const options = {
  resources: ['tcp:4001'],
}

waitOn(options)
  .then(() => {
    server.applyMiddleware({ app })
    app.listen({ port }, () => {
      console.log(
        `Server ready at http://localhost:${port}${server.graphqlPath}`
      )
    })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERR:', err)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, now the services start properly before the gateway starts :)